# Using custom 'Viz' plugin in Apache Superset

Tags: linux, apache-superset

I have been exploring Superset for a while and managed to install Apache Superset on Ubuntu Server without using Docker.

I have followed the following tutorial to create a custom Viz plugin
https://preset.io/blog/2020-07-02-hello-world/

The process of creating a superset Viz plugin was easy to follow. The tutorial says at the end to use `npm run dev-server` to run the dev-server, this works fine and it shows the correct message that my plugin is working.

[Success message for my hello-world plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COo3P.png)

All is very well up to this point. But in my case I have remote control over the laptop that has Ubuntu Server installed with Apache Superset and the dev-server runs at the localhost thus I cannot access it remotely and not test my plugin, what I want is to test my plugin remotely and eventually run the dev-server on '172.17.6.165' so that I can test it with my web browser remotely.

I have tried to edit the `webpack.config.js` to run the server at my desired IP address, but no result. When I run the command `superset run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8088` it will run at '172.17.6.165' but then it won't load my custom created plugin.

When I set all the 'hosts' to my IP address it shows that a proxy is created on *http://172.17.6.165:8088*. And the project is running at *http://172.17.6.165:8088*. This does not work.

Now, what I want to achieve is one of the following below:

1. Access the 'dev-server' remotely
   or
2. Load my plugin to superset so it will load with the command 'superset run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8088'

Answer (score -1):

vim superset-frontend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/options.js
change host:{xxxxxx,default:'localhost'} localhost to 0.0.0.0

npm run dev-server
then you can access on yourhost:9000. but can not get hello world on 8088

Comment: Provide some context in the main text. Not in the comment section. Please edit your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have done that and I can access the dev-server now. However, after lots of testing the plugin wouldn't load. See the issue on Github https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/11694  If you would be able to help me out even more, that would be great.